# git svn dcommit of a cloned TFS repository fails with "Failed to execute WebDAV PROPPATCH:"

Tags: git, svn, version-control

At work I had to use TFS as source code magement system for the last 2 years. I am working with Eclipse and used the plugins and tool chain
provided by Microsoft. After a lot of struggles, performance issues
and lost commits/changes I decided to migrate back to SVN. 
git would be an option but is currently not fully supported in our company.

Here is what I did so far :

- installed git, git-tfs, TortoiseGit (Windows 7 64bit)
- cloned the TFS repo using 

  `git tfs clone https://tfs-repo-url $/tfs-project`
  (this operation run for about 2 days)
- in the cloned repo in .git/config I added 

  `[svn-remote "svn"]
  url = https://svn-repo-url/path/to/repo
  fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn`
- then I run 

  `git svn fetch`
- then I run git rebase using TortoiseGit and the settings

  `branch: master  upstream: remotes/git-svn onto:remotes/git-svn`

  This operation took me 4 days because I had to resolve some conflicts manually
- finally I tried 

  `git svn dcommit`
   both in TortoiseGit and git bash. But it did not work. Error message in both cases :

```
$ git svn dcommit
Committing to https://svn-repo-url/xxx/xxx ...
ERROR from SVN:
Failed to execute WebDAV PROPPATCH: While handling the 'svn:log'     property on '/xxx/xxx/!xxx/xxx/34-11':: Could not execute PROPPATCH.
W: 66bec61cf962b71f4eb58ea4e9563e36979c88b4 and refs/remotes/git-svn differ, using rebase:
:040000 000000 4ed7c4626115cac047944f6c3c319d85fc69d9e5 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D      SomeDir1
:040000 000000 30679e7850bc41f79f849aefa1e841c212fa23a7 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D      SomeDir2
:040000 000000 dc1a6310ac9f4a7872550b6d3da1eae16d77c25a 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D      SomeDir3
:040000 000000 fd55b7817cc1c55ee3e2f19903202daec5348e5a 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D      SomeDir4
:040000 000000 1acbb3d534f38c0197124cd33997d31572f71aed 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D      SomeDir5
:040000 000000 75efb209e1a7fbce240dc2e5e7e7c208ebbdf60b 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D      SomeDir6
Current branch master is up to date.
ERROR: Not all changes have been committed into SVN, however the committed
ones (if any) seem to be successfully integrated into the working tree.
Please see the above messages for details.
```

When I do `git svn dcommit --dry-run` it lists all single commits (in my case ~6100)

What I found so far is that there is something wrong with the commit messages (rich text, multi line). But I really can't see how to modify ~6100 commit messages.

Do you have any idea how to move on here ?

```
versions 
--------
SVN Server : Apache Subversion version 1.7.6 (r1370777)
git : 2.9.0.windows.1
git-tfs : 0.25.0.0 (TFS client library 11.0.0.0 (MS))
TortoiseGit : 2.2.0.0
TortoiseSvn : 1.8.7, Build 25475
```

Best regards

singtur

Comment: Did the commit  messages  accurately in the cloned  TFS repo using git-tfs?

Comment: From what I can see the commit messages in the git-tfs clone look ok.

Comment: I checked the messages using gitk --all . All messages are correctly cloned.